# Fraunhofer's multiple slits versus atomic scatteres (diffraction)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, diffraction

I am currently busy with studying solid state physics and looking at diffraction theory.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/mulslid.html#c3 explains Frauenhofer diffraction good.

Let's assume a N=6 grating. Its diffraction pattern depends on slit width $w$ and slit distance $d$.

But when you have N=6 atomic scatteres (scattering centers) you only have the distance $d$ between them. There is no slit width. But is there a atomic width or something similar?

So how differs the diffraction pattern of 6 slits and 6 atomic scatteres? (1D observation only for now)

Comment: The name is Fraunhofer.

Comment: There is no need for a slit width. Each atom is a very weak scatterer (most x-rays pass straight through millions of atomic layers). It is enough to use the scattering strength per atom, in units of electrons.

Comment: @Pieter So you can say that the diffraction pattern of N=6 slits and N=6 atomic scatteres look like the same? (i.e. like the one in the link in the start post)

Comment: Yes. See also Babinet's principle.

Comment: Ah, I see. Also instead of the slit width $w$ dependence there is a structur factor, which is different for each atom (even only in 1D) and the peak intensity depends on it. Is that a more or less better comparison here?